# Using Dispatch Semaphores with delegate methods

Tags: objective-c, c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

So I have a wrapper class that when I send it a message, it returns YES/NO based on whether the internal object RECEIVED the message. Meaning, when I send this, it doesn't actually return when the task is done. I also want to make sure that only one task is executed at a time, so I use dispatch semaphores. My wrapper class calls a delegate method to notify me that it finished processing the internal task.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.all", 0); // private queue
dispatch_semaphore_t semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(1); // one at a time
...
- (void)doStuff:(NSString *)stuff {
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    dispatch_sync(queue, ^(void) {
        [myWrapperObject sendRequestToInternalStuff:stuff];
    }
}
...
- (void)myWrapperClassProcessingIsDone {
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore);
}
```

This doesn't work, and it hangs. How can I implement something like this without hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone needs to know, there is no way to do this. The semaphore locks the thread, so you would have to have a separate spawned thread with a run-loop waiting for a variable change. I just re-worked my code to avoid semaphores.

Comment: So what did you do instead of dispatch semaphores? I am in a similar position, needing to wait for a copy method to actually finish before I start another copy block.

Comment: I replaced it with a queue-based implementation- requests can queue up on the stack, and it's up to the internals to handle the requests in the queue. Then I created a quick internal intermediate-subclass that locks up its own thread when the queue is full. This way, I don't have to worry about locking both ends of the PDO.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ensure that only one task is executed at a time, the correct approach is to execute each task on the same serial GCD queue.  A serial queue always executes just one task at a time.  The `dispatch_queue_create` function creates a serial queue when you pass 0 (or `DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL` or `NULL`) as the second argument..

Comment: Yes, but my "task" on my queue is actually a Portable Distributed Object message. When it returns, it just means the task was sent to the external process- not that it completed. I need to wait for the task to complete (upon which the PDO object hits a callback on me).